# how to get particular information in particular variable from table

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company-officers/MPAPss.BO"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'dataTable'})
for row in table.find_all("tr"):
    for col in row.find_all("td"):
        print(col.text)
```

it prints the all information simultaneously(name,year and designation) i want to store name in name section using

```
name = col[0].text
```

but it gives the the error how i solve this?

Comment: What error? Also, `clo` != `col`.

Comment: @roganjosh i try with col not clo: the error is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asn\Desktop\program\scrap\scrap_reuters.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(col[0].text)
  File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1011, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0

Comment: Ok, I also asked what the error is. You should include the full traceback.

Comment: If you don't know what to do when you get valid answers against your post, why create one @Pratap? Please follow this link to learn the procedure 
[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @MITHU Thanks for Advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> for row in table.find_all("tr"):
...     cols = row.find_all("td")
...     if not cols:
...         continue
...     name, year, des = filter(None, [col.text.strip() for col in cols])
...     print (f'Name: {name}, Year: {year}, Des: {des}')
... 
Name: K. Ratna Prabha, Year: 2014, Des: Non-Executive Chairman of the Board
Name: Mohan Kulkarni, Year: 2012, Des: Compliance Officer, Company Secretary
Name: Naveen Singh, Year: 2014, Des: Managing Director, Executive Director
Name: B. Khanna, Year: 2014, Des: Non-Executive Director - Nominee of BIFR
Name: V. Rammohan, Year: 2013, Des: Non-Executive Director - Nominee of IFCI
Name: Aravind Shrivastava, Year: 2013, Des: Non-Executive Director
Name: M. Lakshminarayana, Year: 2009, Des: Non-Executive Independent Director
Name: C. Okaly, Year: 2010, Des: Non-Executive Independent Director
Name: S. Parameswarappa, Year: 1996, Des: Non-Executive Independent Director
Name: C. Shivashankar, Year: 1995, Des: Non-Executive Independent Director
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way you might wanna give atry:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company-officers/MPAPss.BO"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'dataTable'})
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1::1]:
    col = row.find_all("td")
    name = col[0].get_text(strip=True)
    year = col[2].get_text(strip=True)
    position = col[3].get_text(strip=True)
    print("Name: {} Year: {} Position: {}".format(name,year,position))
```

Output:

```
Name: K. Ratna Prabha Year: 2014 Position: Non-Executive Chairman of the Board
Name: Mohan Kulkarni Year: 2012 Position: Compliance Officer, Company Secretary
Name: Naveen Singh Year: 2014 Position: Managing Director, Executive Director
Name: B. Khanna Year: 2014 Position: Non-Executive Director - Nominee of BIFR
Name: V. Rammohan Year: 2013 Position: Non-Executive Director - Nominee of IFCI
Name: Aravind Shrivastava Year: 2013 Position: Non-Executive Director
Name: M. Lakshminarayana Year: 2009 Position: Non-Executive Independent Director
Name: C. Okaly Year: 2010 Position: Non-Executive Independent Director
Name: S. Parameswarappa Year: 1996 Position: Non-Executive Independent Director
Name: C. Shivashankar Year: 1995 Position: Non-Executive Independent Director
```

Comment: your code is good but it prints only(alternative value)1st, 3rd, 5th and so on. it neglect the value  of 2nd 4th and so on. when i try with for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:, it works fine.

Comment: Right you are @Pratap, because it should be `table.find_all("tr")[1::1]` not `table.find_all("tr")[1::2]`. However, fixed it to reflect the changes.